# Incompatible gradle versions - Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

My gradle file is not throwing any error while building. But, when I run Android lint, it fails with incompatible gradle version error.

Sharing the error:

**Incompatible Gradle Versions**

> ../../build.gradle: All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 16.0.2, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.1.0, 15.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:16.0.2 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:16.0.1**

Sharing the google dependencies defined in app level gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Project level gradle file:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

Which dependency making this lint error? How to solve this gradle incompatibility issue?

I have tried changing all google gms versions to 15, but it didn't solved the issue..

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Comment: Try to use the same version of the same type of dependencies. e.g: all dependencies of `com.google.android.gms:play-services...` should be the same version(like your all `com.android.support:...` dependencies are in save version).

Comment: use the latest versions mentioned in doc https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you are using an **old** plugin

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

and different versions of the Google Services libraries.

**You should update the** [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // ...
}
```

**Then update your [dependencies](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)** **but it not necessary to use the same version**.

Starting from plugin 3.3.0 there is a different behaviour:

> Google Play services libraries after 15.0.0 now have independent
>   version numbers which follow SemVer. This change will allow for more
>   frequent, flexible updates by individual components. The Google
>   Services Gradle plugin has been updated to version 3.3.0 to support
>   this change in versioning.

Check also the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#remove_old_anti-pattern):
**REMOVE THIS OLD PATTERN:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        play_version = '15.0.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    // DON’T DO THIS!!
    // The following use of the above buildscript property is no longer valid.
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${play_version}"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:${play_version}"
}
```

**Now each dependency that you use may now be at different versions.**

Comment: Updating google service plugin to latest version, gradle plugin to latest version and all gms & firebase dependencies to latest version solved my issue. Thanks Gabriele :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> All com.google.android.gms libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 16.0.2, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.1.0, 15.0.1.

is very clearly telling that

This is what you have right now:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
```

it must be:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.2'
```

Also, try to always use the latest version of Google APIs.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It is not correct. Since the 3.3.0 google play services plugin, each dependency that you use may now be at different versions. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/versioning#remove_old_anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

You need to update gradle build tools to this version:-

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

and google play services

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to [@Nouman Ch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55099013/6478047) answer , These are the latest dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)  and  [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)  for finding latest versions

Comment: You have to update the google play services plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project view of android studio. There in .idea> libraries you'll find libraries with versions 16.0.2, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.1.0, 15.0.1.

[image]

These libraries are imported as dependencies of the ones you have in your build.gradle file.  Import the latest versions of those libraries in your dependencies to remove the error.